# How to prevent inserting question marks (???) in MySQL while working with C#.NET?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unicode, character-encoding

As a PHP developer, I always use the code below whenever I want to work with PHP and MySQL on Unicode contents:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die (mysql_error());
if ($link) {
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
    $db = mysql_select_db("mydb") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

In this case all contents will store exactly in MySQL database.

Now, I have a windows application written in C#.NET and I have to join it with MySQL database and store something in database through it.  But all contents save as `???` marks.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you please post an example???

Comment: I think you're inserting Arabic text, am I right?

Comment: @AzizAG, it's similar to Arabic. It's Farsi (Persian)

Comment: @paulsm4 the source of C# windows application is not accessible for me. Another group is working on it, they just told me this problem. However, I will try to ask them to give me their code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell your C# code that the MySQL database uses UTF8 encoding by including that information in your connection string, e.g.:

```
Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=MyUsername;Pwd=MyPassword;Charset=utf8;
```

Comment: I was going to post this myself.  You're absolutely correct: the .Net connection string must specify "utf8".  I'm just checking if there are any *other* gotcha's the OP needs to be aware of.  A code snippet would definitely be helpful...

Comment: It surely would.  If this is a web app for example, there's ample opportunity for an encoding problem between browser and server (though the OP specifies it is a windows app).